# How to Use formControlName in <fieldset>

Tags: angular, typescript

using the below template iam creating a calender component, every thing is working fine but i need to access date with formControlName like below.

this.formControlName.get('Name').value === MM/DD/YYYY

```
<fieldset class="field">
  <legend class="lable">date</legend>
   <div class="date-input" id="date" formControlName="Name" (change)="onDateChnage" #dateInput>
     <span class="date-part">
       <input name="year">
     </span>
     <span class="date-part">
       <input name="month">
     </span>
     <span class="date-part">
       <input name="date">
     </span>
     <button class="calender" aria-lable="calendar</button>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Send formControlName to your method :

```
<div class="date-input" id="date" (change)="onChangeDate($event,'Name')">
```

And then in your component.ts file :

```
 onChangeDate(date,controlName) {
    this.addEditForm.get(controlName).reset(date);
  }
```

Comment: in a div you has no (change) event :(

Comment: Please visit https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: I visited, but, sorry, I can not see what do you want to say. In mat-datepicker there no event "(change)" ( if you see the API you see that thre're a event (a output) "dateChange") and you need applied to a "input" : `<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" (dateChange)="yourFunction($event)">`. a "class" NOT "convert" a div or a input in "somemore", is the directive `[matDatePicker]` who makes the "input" some special. -It's true that If you see the DOM you see the class aplied but you need write in your .html the "directive"

Answer (score 0):

You can Access individual controls in the group:

in TS file;

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  formDate: FormGroup;
  constructor() {
    this.formDate = new FormGroup({
      Name: new FormGroup({
 
        year: new FormControl('', [
        ]),
        month: new FormControl('', [
        ]),
        day: new FormControl('', [
        ])

      })
     
    });
  }

   onSubmit() {
     let value = this.formDate.value.Name
     let getValue = `${value.year}/${value.month}/${value.day}`
     console.log(getValue)
   }

  
}
```

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="formDate" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<fieldset class="field" formGroupName="Name" >
<legend class="lable">date</legend>
<div class="date-input" id="date" #dateInput>
  <span class="date-part">
  <input type="text" formControlName="year" placeholder="year">
  </span>
  <span class="date-part">
  <input type="text" formControlName="month" placeholder="month">
  </span>
  <span class="date-part">
  <input type="text" formControlName="day" placeholder="day">
  </span>
  <button class="calender" aria-lable="calendar">click</button>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

You can visit the demo in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2tzegj?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: What ever the code i given is already under one from group to pass date to that FormGroup i need use a formControlName

Comment: you can take advantage of adding one group to another to access all the input values `this.formDate = new FormGroup({. Name: new FormGroup({ ...`

Comment: i need date as a string with formgroup the output is no excepted

Comment: You cannot access a group of inputs by a single control group, there are several solutions for this; I have answered you with this `FormGroup` nested in a `FormGroup` and create a simple logic in the method to transform them as you want like string.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way:

**html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <input [formControlName]="'date'" type="date" name="date">
</form>
```

**ts**

```
 
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      date: [null, []]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form.get('date').valueChanges.subscribe(dat => {
      console.log(dat);
      this.getDetailsDate(dat);
    });
  }
```

If you want more details you can use something like this:

```
getDetailsDate(date: Date) {
    let new_date = new Date(date);
    console.log('Full Year: ', new_date.getFullYear());
    console.log('Month: ', new_date.getMonth());
    console.log('Day: ', new_date.getDay());
  }
```

Here an exammple
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vfcvum?file=src/app/app.component.ts